# How to direct to POST action in ActionAsPDF?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5, rotativa

I am creating an MVC 5 application. I am using Rotativa to generate PDFs

they have a method called

```
public ActionAsPdf(string action, object routeValues);
```

I am having trouble to direct to POST method of an action

this is that **GET** and **POST** actions

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create_Brochure(IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> model)
    {
        .............

        return View(selectedIDs);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create_Brochure(string m)
    {                                

        return View();
    }
```

Once I run this program its directing to GET method but I want to direct to POST action

using following method

```
    public ActionResult PrintIndex()
    {
        return new ActionAsPdf("Create_Brochure") { FileName = "Test.pdf" };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the parameters of the `POST` version of `Create_Brochure`:

```
return new ActionAsPdf("Create_Brochure", new List<ProductsPropertiesVM>())
{
    FileName = "Test.pdf"
};
```

Of course, you'll have to pass the correct `model` data instead of the `List<ProductsPropertiesVM>`.

Comment: but then model getting null

Comment: Missed `)` at the end :P

Comment: it should be `new List<ProductsPropertiesVM>()) {FileName="Test.pdf"};`